# Extending Plot on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extend the plot function to use a custom plot function in conjunction with the existing pandas' plot functions.  What is the best way to do this?

If I override `plot()` I lose the ability to get to the old functions correct? or is there some way I can still call the old plot functions?

**Update**

I can use super() to call the parent's class and it appears to be working quite well.  If this is a poor solution, please post an answer!

```
import pandas as pd
class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'kind' in kwargs and \
           kwargs['kind'].lower() == 'dotmapplot':
           return _custom_plot(*args, **kwargs)
        else: 
          super(CustomDataFrame, self).plot(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you

Comment: `pandas`'s `plot` returns `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` object (or an array of them), you can use it to further plot what you need without having to override

Comment: @bluesummers can you post a sample of what you mean?

Comment: @bluesummers this seems to work: ```super(CustomDataFrame, self).plot(*args, **kwargs)```

Comment: what I mean is if you use `ax = df.plot(...)` you can later use `ax` object to change whatever you want. For example you could `ax.set_title("My New Title")`